# Doctrine Query Language, Two joins query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with dql. I can't write properly query. Need to rewrite the query to dql

> ```
>               'SELECT 
>                     Movie.title, Movie.price, Order.order_data, Order.order_status 
>                     FROM 
>                     (Order LEFT JOIN Order_has_Movie ON Order.order_id = Order_has_Movie.order_id)
>                     INNER JOIN Movie ON Order_has_Movie.movie_id = Movie.movie_id 
>                     ORDER BY 
>                     title DESC'
> ```
>
> At the beginning, I wrote something like this:

```
'SELECT 
                    m.title, m.price, o.order_data, o.order_status 
                    FROM
```

And I don't know how to deal with this. Could someone tell me, how to wrtie JOINS like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a many-to-many association between order and movie you can set your entities to achieve this relation something like below

**Order Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\Movie", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Order_has_Movie",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="movie_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $movies;
```

**Movie Entity**

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\Order", mappedBy="movies")
 */
private $order;
```

Now in query builder you can join your order entity with movie like below

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->select('o,m')
        ->innerJoin('o.movies','m')
        ->orderBy('m.title','DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Above query will orders and its related movies

For further clarification see docs [`22.2.19. @ManyToMany`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytomany)